# What are effective fail-safes to prevent accidental transfer of coins/tokens/nfts to a non-existing wallet?

Tags: transactions, transfer

I came across the "--allow-unfunded-recipient" flag for the CLI transfer subcommand (there should also be a JSON RPC equivalent) and I started wondering if ***not adding that flag*** would be an effective way to ensure that the target wallet exists for the transfer transaction to be successful. The examples I came across use that flag, so I wonder if some down-sides are associated with omitting it, and if so, what other fail-safes there might be.

Is that an effective fail-safe for this? Are there also other more-or-less effective fail-safes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recipient wallet might not have a token account to accept tokens of a particular mint, and it should be handled in the app itself.

Currently, the flow is

1. Get the associated token address for the user public key and the token mint
2. Check if the token account exists for that address
3. If not, create an associated token account for the user for that mint
4. Send and confirm the transaction
5. Now make the RPC call

Example:

```
const handleSendTokens = async () => {
    const { publicKey } = useWallet();
    const tokenMint = new PublicKey("TokenMint")

    const transaction = new Transaction();

    const takerDepositTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        tokenMint,
        publicKey
    );

    try {
        await getAccount(connection, takerDepositTokenAccount);
    } catch (e) {
        transaction.add(
            createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
                publicKey,
                takerDepositTokenAccount,
                publicKey,
                tokenMint,
            )
        );
    }

    await provider.sendAndConfirm(transaction);

    await program.methods...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into escrows because escrows allow you to send funds but also allow you to refund if no one receives it on the other end.

[Here's an example tutorial from Paul himself.](https://paulx.dev/blog/2021/01/14/programming-on-solana-an-introduction/)